# How To Change Background Color In Hex Dynamically in Angular2?

Tags: angular

Converting decimal value to hex value in Angular to change `background-color` dynamically. Here is the component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `

        <h1>Change Background Color Dynamically</h1>

        <!-- Chang Background Color By Increasing Or Decreasing Color Value -->
        <button (click)="bgColor = bgColor + 15">+</button>
        <button (click)="bgColor = bgColor - 15">-</button>

        <div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': '#' + bgColor}">
          Changable Background Color
       </div>

      `
    })

    export class AppComponent { 

        bgColor;

      constructor() { 
        this.bgColor = 'BBFFFF';
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you'll have to convert hex to decimal add/subtract 15 then convert to back to hex:

> plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/e4Vl9amWbLsE46Aeam4s?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Change Background Color Dynamically</h1>

    <!-- Chang Background Color By Increasing Or Decreasing Color Value -->
    <button (click)="add()">+</button>
    <button (click)="subtract()">-</button>

    <div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': '#' + bgColor}">
      Changable Background Color
   </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  bgColor: string;
  constructor() {
    this.bgColor = 'BBFFFF';
  }
  toHex(decimalNum){return decimalNum.toString(16); }
  toDecimal(hexString){return parseInt(hexString, 16);; }

  add(){
    var decimalPlus15 = this.toDecimal(this.bgColor) + 15;
    this.bgColor = this.toHex(decimalPlus15)
  }
  subtract(){
    var decimalPlus15 = this.toDecimal(this.bgColor) - 15;
    this.bgColor = this.toHex(decimalPlus15)
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.